# Prefix/suffix column content with column names

Tags: r, dplyr, tidy

I want to mutate column content of a data frame so that the cell content is prefixed by the column name:

```
> x <- data.frame(VarX = rep(c("A","B"),2), VarY = rep(c("C","D"),2))
> x
  VarX VarY
1    A    C
2    B    D
3    A    C
4    B    D
> x$VarX <- paste0("VarX", x$VarX)
> x$VarY <- paste0("VarY", x$VarY)
> x
   VarX  VarY
1 VarXA VarYC
2 VarXB VarYD
3 VarXA VarYC
4 VarXB VarYD
```

but in generic. The closes furthest I got is by:

```
x <- data.frame(VarX = rep(c("A","B"),2), VarY = rep(c("C","D"),2))
columns = c("VarX", "VarY")

for(col in columns)
{
  x <- x %>% mutate_at( .vars = col, ~paste0(col, .) )
}
x
```

but i do not like the for loop. Can anyone improve the code?

Please also note the code to work on column selection of x.

```
x <- data.frame(VarX = rep(c("A","B"),2), VarY = rep(c("C","D"),2),
  num = 1:4)
```

and I only want to modify the column VarX and VarY.

Comment: I haven't used R in a while properly but have you looked into what stringr can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `imap`, which would also include the column names of each column if we need to extract.  Here, we `paste` the column names (`.y`) with the column values (`.x`)

```
library(tidyverse)
imap(x, ~ paste0(.y, .x)) %>%
    bind_cols
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  VarX  VarY 
#   <chr> <chr>
#1 VarXA VarYC
#2 VarXB VarYD
#3 VarXA VarYC
#4 VarXB VarYD
```

EDIT: Based on comments from @Moody_Mudskipper

```
imap_dfc(x, ~ paste0(.y, .x))
```

---

Or using `base R`, we `paste` the replicated column names of 'x' with `matrix` of 'x' and assign it to the initial data.frame

```
x[] <- paste0(rep(colnames(x), each = nrow(x)), as.matrix(x))
x
#   VarX  VarY
#1 VarXA VarYC
#2 VarXB VarYD
#3 VarXA VarYC
#4 VarXB VarYD
```

Comment: `imap_dfc(x, ~ paste0(.y, .x))` will spare you the `bind_cols` call

Answer (score 2):

You can try `mapply`, i.e.

```
x[] <- mapply(paste0, names(x), x)
```

which gives,

> ```
>    VarX  VarY
> 1 VarXA VarYC
> 2 VarXB VarYD
> 3 VarXA VarYC
> 4 VarXB VarYD
> ```

Comment: This returns a matrix.

Comment: Not If you assign it back to the data frame, i.e. `x[] <- ...`

Comment: Still there is a matrix conversion going on, if you just use `Map` instead it will be more efficient and more explicit (`mapply` 60% less efficient with a quick microbenchmark on this example on my side).

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lapply`

```
x[] <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) paste0(names(x)[i], x[,i]))
x

#   VarX  VarY
#1 VarXA VarYC
#2 VarXB VarYD
#3 VarXA VarYC
#4 VarXB VarYD
```

You can use appropriate `sep` argument in `paste0` to make it look clean.

---

If you have more number of columns and you want to select only some of them you can do

```
cols <- c("VarX","VarY")
x[cols] <- lapply(seq_along(x[cols]), function(i) paste0(names(x)[i], x[,i]))

x
#   VarX  VarY num
#1 VarXA VarYC   1
#2 VarXB VarYD   2
#3 VarXA VarYC   3
#4 VarXB VarYD   4
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `purrr`:

```
purrr::map2_dfc(colnames(x), x, paste0)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  V1    V2   
  <chr> <chr>
1 VarXA VarYC
2 VarXB VarYD
3 VarXA VarYC
4 VarXB VarYD
```

If you have more columns this works also, just subset by the ones that you need to change:

```
cols <- c("VarX", "VarY")
x[, cols] <- purrr::map2_dfc(cols, x[,cols], paste0)
x
#    VarX  VarY VarZ
# 1 VarXA VarYC    E
# 2 VarXB VarYD    F
# 3 VarXA VarYC    E
# 4 VarXB VarYD    F
```

Data:

```
x <- data.frame(VarX = rep(c("A","B"),2), 
                VarY = rep(c("C","D"),2), 
                VarZ = rep(c("E","F"),2))
```

Comment: I thought about it but this drops the column names.

Comment: you can reassign with `x[] <- `  as @Sotos said

Comment: if you use `set_names` in your call, no need you can get the right output without reassigning to the variable (and if you reassign to the variable you don't need the `_dfc` :) ) : `purrr::map2_dfc(set_names(colnames(x)), x, paste0)`, you can also just switch the order of arguments as `x` is named : `purrr::map2_dfc(x,colnames(x), ~paste0(.y,.x))`, but better to use `imap` as in @akrun's comment, or `imap_dfc` as I suggest in my comment under his answer

Answer (score 0):

In base `r`

```
data.frame(matrix(paste0(sort(rep(names(x),4L)), unlist(x)), ncol = 2))
```